# Hosting provider requires giving out server's admin password because of Microsoft audit

Tags: windows, sql-server, password

I am using a Windows OS VPS from a smaller, local provider for 1 year, everything was good until I started to license a MSSQL Web from the provider itself. They ask me to share my OS's admin password with them because the Microsoft Audit.
Is it a normal thing to ask for? If I don't share it with them they deactivate my license.
What would you do?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd look for another provider, but first safeguard anything worthwile you've got on that server.

Comment: I'd politely answer with a "no" when asked by my provider for an administrator account and proceed from there. IMHO their audit and compliance is not immediately your problem. A hosting provider shouldn't need access to your system(s) to report to Microsoft on what image and what additional licenses they provide you with.

Comment: First I told them, that I am not willing to share the password with them. Now they want to terminate my license contract. I guess I will need to move to another provider.